# syntax error in update statement in vb.net with access database

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

Sorry, I tried many times to figure out where the problem is and I found nothing, the error I get is "syntax error in update statement".

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim pos As Integer = BindingContext(clientsDT).Position
    With clientsDT.Rows(pos)
        .Item("Client_ID") = Client_IDTextBox.Text
        .Item("Company_name") = Company_nameTextBox.Text
        .Item("Address") = AddressTextBox.Text
        .Item("City") = CityTextBox.Text
        .Item("Personnel") = PersonnelTextBox.Text
        .Item("Personnel_Gender") = Personnel_GenderComboBox.Text
        .Item("Personnel_Phone") = Personnel_PhoneTextBox.Text
        .Item("Client_Value") = Client_ValueTextBox.Text
        .Item("Client_Added by") = Added_byTextBox.Text
        .Item("Date_added") = Date_AddedDateTimePicker.Value
        .Item("Time_added") = Time_AddedDateTimePicker.Value
    End With
    Try
        Dim save As New OleDbCommandBuilder(clientsDA)
        clientsDA.Update(clientsDT)
        clientsDT.AcceptChanges()
        MsgBox("Data Saved Successfully")
        load_clients()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

this error I get whenever I tried to manipulate the database whether by updating or adding new data.
please find attached, the error I always get 
[exception error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyriq.png)

[the second error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLVlq.png)

Comment: the second error looks like the result of letting the user set/pick the ID.  how can they know what to enter in `Client_IDTextBox`

Comment: @Plutonix that's pretty good !! Thanks a lot !! I guess i found where the problem is !!!

Comment: If it is an AI number, let the database assign it since that is its job

Comment: @Plutonix it is, yes you guided me to the right way!! Thanks a lot !! Appreciate your great help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to hazard a guess that it's the space in the field name on this line:

```
.Item("Client_Added by") = Added_byTextBox.Text
```

Comment: actually i added another error, i always get, could you please check it